# simple form to send email

Tags: php

I want to show whether email sent successfully or failed on the same form. I want to show the empty form after email sent successfully. How can i do it?
here is the form

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
<span>here i want to show msg<span>
```

Comment: Define "successfully". There is no way to tell if, for example, an email was marked as spam and silently thrown away.

Comment: @David Dorward: I would define "sent successfully" as "delivered to the SMTP server without error." Beyond that, it's outside the scope of the application :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) will return `TRUE` "if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery", so I guess have the form submit to the same page, handle the data using PHP at the top, save the return value of the `mail()` function in a variable, and handle that boolean value in that variable in order to display what you want to display.

Answer (score 2):

[php mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
this will help. There are some examples.
*Remember! accepted for delivery is NOT the same as Delivered!*

Comment: You should use this really carefully, if anybody finds a way to use your `mail()` function, he'll will be able to use your server to send spam.